# change highlight color on click bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: bootstrap-4

When you click on a dropdown menu item, it is highlighted in blue. How can I change this color?

```
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownButton';

function ButtonDarkExample() {
  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown>
        <Dropdown.Toggle id="dropdown-button-dark-example1" variant="secondary">
          Dropdown Button
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu variant="dark">
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1" active>
            Action
          </Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Divider />
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-4">Separated link</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>

      <DropdownButton
        id="dropdown-button-dark-example2"
        variant="secondary"
        menuVariant="dark"
        title="Dropdown button"
        className="mt-2"
      >
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1" active>
          Action
        </Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Divider />
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-4">Separated link</Dropdown.Item>
      </DropdownButton>
    </>
  );
}

export default ButtonDarkExample;
```

I am a beginner in programming. I read the bootstrap documentation, nothing helped

Comment: For questions about CSS you should be showing us rendered HTML, not JSX. Please tag CSS. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the click background color of a Bootstrap dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484241/how-can-i-change-the-click-background-color-of-a-bootstrap-dropdown)